# Journey Builder - Ad Audience - Create Exclusion Audience so I don't advertise to certain customers or customers who have seen the ad

Tags: marketing-cloud, ad-studio

I'm trying to understand how to build a suppression audience for ad studio in journey builder.

'Customers that exit journeys aren’t automatically removed from that Advertising Audience, so it’s important to add in this suppression step to avoid retargeting the same customers. '

I have added in my email and ad campaign activities in to my journey. What do I do to get them to exit the audience and not re-enter once they have been through - how do i create a suppression audience?

I tried to see other questions but it just said add in a suppression audience which is not clear to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically create another Ad Audience in the journey that you will use as a suppression audience on FB or Google (or whatever ad channel).

So contacts enter the first audience (audience A) and get the ad. Then you put a Wait for however long (say 10 days) and then they enter another Ad Audience (audience B), which is your suppression. On the ad networks side, when you configure the campaign, you say use audience A as the recipients of the ad, and use audience B as suppression.

Honestly, I find this approach cumbersome, not to mention it consumes two of your Ad Studio audiences instead of one. There are other ways to tackle this but I won't go into them here.

Comment: I was looking for the function to supress from the MC side and thought I was really missing something. This helps so much- thank you!